# Cyclic Strip Time bug if the action doesn't start at frame 0

Tags: nla-editor

I tried to use cyclic strip time for an action that started at like frame 6000, but it wouldn't work at all. I had to move the action to frame 0 and then just move the stripe back to frame 6000 for it to work again. I saw one other thread somewhere else from like 2021 that it happened to multiple people and is a bug or whatever, so I'm just wondering if anyone else experienced this and if they had a better work around than what I wrote earlier.